Is suffering inherent in life?
I read the following on the internet:

The Truth of Suffering (Dukkha): Life involves suffering,
dissatisfaction, and impermanence. This suffering is inherent in
birth, aging, illness, and death.
The Truth of the Cessation of Suffering (Nirodha): It is possible to end suffering by eliminating attachment, craving, and ignorance.

If suffering is inherent in life, how can suffering be ended while being alive? Must I commit suicide to end suffering? Is committing suicide eliminating attachment, craving and ignorance? What exactly did the Buddha teach in this First Noble Truth?

Breathing and being alive is not the same as "having a life". Having properties, having titles, having preferences, that's having a life. That's birth. That's difficulty, it's not about breath and being alive.

the word "birth" does not mean biological birth

Sentience is suffering, not specifically life as there are realms of experience without a physical body but consisting just of mind. The cessation is the cessation of cyclical existence, as it one will no longer be reborn into sentience.

sounds like superstition. all the best

How so? The 31 realms of samsara explains there are realms of just mind, pretty sure the index of information somewhere here in the help section has the explanations of such places. As too does the true cessation/nibanna and even Buddhas explanation(s) on "where" the Buddha goes after death indicates ending of arising, no rebirth. it is the whole point.  I think the mistake or misunderstanding here will be the word "life" and what does that mean. I myself would use the word "existence" over life as again some forms (or formless) beings do not have "life" they inhabit sentience in existence.

Samsara means attachment - refer to SN 22.99. The realms are merely mental states or psychological archetypes.

Buddha taught that Sabbe Sankhara Dukkha. In other words we can say

Now this is the noble truth of suffering. Rebirth is suffering; old
age is suffering; illness is suffering; death is suffering;
association with the disliked is suffering; separation from the liked
is suffering; not getting what you wish for is suffering. In brief,
the five grasping aggregates are suffering.

As mentioned in SN 56.11
Committing suicide won’t solve the problem because the cravings persists. Return to life is inevitable if cravings are left.
Before saying life is suffering we must define what is life? If life is defined as involving lust , aversion and delusion then definitely life is suffering.

Hi. Is Sabbe Sankhara Dukkha mentioned n SN 56.11?

Hi. Was the Buddha alive? Did the Buddha (who was free from  lust , aversion and delusion) have a "life"?

@DhammaDhatu Oh no. Sabbe Sankhara Dukkha is not mentioned in SN 56.11. Buddha had attained Nibbana but was not fully extinguished. He suffered at his deathbed. He was alive at that moment. Full extinguishment results in full cessation of suffering. Full extinguishment can not be defined as life.
